# Do other endgame crisis appear if I am already the crisis?

Tags: stellaris

In the new expansion for Stellaris, Nemesis, the player can become the endgame crisis.

I wanted to know if the AI endgame crisis will still spawn if I have already become the endgame crisis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the forums](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/threads/player-crisis-and-normal-crisis-both-happen.1471565/post-27493985), yes, an endgame crisis can still occur after you (or an AI, or both) Become the Crisis.

> Completely intended that player (or AI) empires taking the ascension perk doesn't stop the end-game crisis from spawning.

Other reports in that thread indicate that other crises still occur too (the Khan, the War in Heaven, etc.).